# Mocking static method of the interface in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

I got an interface with a static method in it. And I want to mock this method for unit tests.
Here's an example of such an interface:

```
public interface IClass {
  static String create(String s) {
    System.out.println("Method create is called");
    return s;
  }
}
```

I was trying to mock this method using `PowerMockito`:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(IClass.class)
public class IClassTest {

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(IClass.class);
    ClassImpl cl = mock(ClassImpl.class);
    Mockito.when(IClass.create(any())).thenReturn(cl);
  }

  @Test
  public void mockInterfaceClassTest() {
    System.out.println(IClass.create("Test"));
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, the mocking is not being done and even more, as soon as in my `setUp()` method I'm trying to setup mock: `Mockito.when(IClass.create(any())).thenReturn(cl);` actually, the method is being called (I got message in console "Method create is called"), which is undesired for sure.

Is there any possibility to mock **static** method inside **interface**?

Comment: How can you define a method in an interface? An interface method is always overriden in the class that implements the interface. It's illegal to define methods inside interfaces - that's what I know.

Comment: @ProgyadeepMoulik, it was true before Java8...

Comment: There isn't a reasonable way to do this. You could "mock" it by intercepting calls with AspectJ or something similar but I'd say it's much less effort to not try & do such things.

Comment: @TeemuIlmonen, I got no other choice, as far as it's a part of 3rd-party lib. If it was my code ...

Comment: It should work fine with JMockit: just declare a `@Mocked IClass mock` field, and record the desired expectation on the static method.

Comment: @Rogério, I will try with `JMockit` and I will write here about the result.